# PIVOT SQL - Colunas Dinâmicas com Variável

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Tenho uma tabela a qual transformo linhas em colunas com o PIVOT. 'Chumbando' o nome das colunas, funciona muito bem, todavia vou precisar fazer isso dinamicamente. Existe a possibilidade de usar variáveis para definir o nome das colunas?

```
        SELECT PRODUTO,
           ISNULL([@MES3],0) AS MES3,
           ISNULL([@MES2],0) AS MES2,
           ISNULL([@MES1],0) AS MES1,
           ISNULL([@MES0],0) AS MESATUAL
        FROM #VENDASESTM 
             PIVOT (SUM(QTDVEND) FOR EMISSAO IN ([@MES3],[@MES2],[@MES1],[@MES0]) )P
        ORDER BY PRODUTO
```

Estes 4 meses são dinâmicos e informados na chamada da Store Procedure. A SP cria a tabela #VENDASESTM corretamente com os produtos, meses escolhidos e quantidades vendidas. Depois preciso transformar isso com o PIVOT também dinamicamente.

Do jeito que está acima, o resultado foi 0 em todas as colunas. Fiz a conferência e há vendas, então algo está errado.

Comment: Se você fazer o select alterando as variáveis mês (exe; @MES3), por um valor fixo (exe; 3) ele funcionar ?

Comment: Sim @MarconcílioSouza [05],[06],[07] e etc chumbados funciona perfeitamente. Mas agora eu preciso que as colunas sejam determinadas pelo retorno da variável

Comment: Qual banco de dados e o tipo da coluna EMISSAO :?

Comment: Banco de Dados SQL e EMISSAO como Caractere de 2

Comment: [SQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), não é banco de dados, o seu Caractere de 2 você falar varchar(2)? o banco é sql server?

Comment: Só esqueci do restante do nome do SQL, rs. SQL SERVER 2008
Acabei de mudar para VarChar(2) para fazer um teste, antes estava apenas como Char... está processando a query (é meio pesada e o servidor é lento). Vamos ver o resultado.

Comment: Deu na mesma, retornou tudo zerado

Comment: seu paramentro @MES3 também é do mesmo tipo?

Comment: Sim, os 4 meses são do mesmo tipo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você conseguir fazer o seu PIVOT passando parâmetros terá que passar seu select para uma variável varchar e depois usar o execute para executar a query da seguinte forma.

```
declare @MES2 varchar(2) = '02', @MES3 varchar(2) = '03', @MES1 varchar(2) ='01', @MES0 varchar(2) ='00' 
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @query = '
declare @VENDASESTM table
(
   PRODUTO int,
   QTDVEND int,
   EMISSAO varchar(2)
)


insert into @VENDASESTM values
(1,1,''01''),
(2,1,''02''),
(3,1,''03''),
(3,1,''00''),
(4,1,''04''),
(2,1,''02'')

SELECT PRODUTO, 
        ISNULL([' +@MES3 +'],0) AS MES3,
        ISNULL([' +@MES2+'],0) AS MES2,
        ISNULL([' +@MES1+'],0) AS MES1,
        ISNULL([' +@MES0+'],0) AS MESATUAL
        FROM @VENDASESTM vc
             PIVOT  (SUM(QTDVEND) FOR EMISSAO IN ([' +@MES3+'],[' +@MES2+'],[' +@MES1+'],[' +@MES0+']) )P
        ORDER BY PRODUTO';

execute(@query);
```

No seu caso só o trecho abaixo.

```
set @query = '
SELECT PRODUTO, 
        ISNULL([' +@MES3 +'],0) AS MES3,
        ISNULL([' +@MES2+'],0) AS MES2,
        ISNULL([' +@MES1+'],0) AS MES1,
        ISNULL([' +@MES0+'],0) AS MESATUAL
        FROM @VENDASESTM vc
             PIVOT  (SUM(QTDVEND) FOR EMISSAO IN ([' +@MES3+'],[' +@MES2+'],[' +@MES1+'],[' +@MES0+']) )P
        ORDER BY PRODUTO';

execute(@query);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado