# Efetuar select com coluna dinâmica

Tags: sql-server

Possuo uma consulta com `N` relacionamentos, em uma dessas tabelas relacionadas eu preciso selecionar uma coluna em específico que segue o padrão `mes_valor`, onde `mes` é uma abreviação para um dos doze possíveis `jan_valor`, `fev_valor`, `..._valor`.

O `SELECT` é algo como:

`SELECT [dbo.mes_valor(MONTH(tabela_relacionada.data_emissao))] as valor FROM tabela`

Onde a partir da data de emissão, obterei o mês e selecionarei a coluna específica para obter o valor necessário. `dbo.mes_valor` é uma função simples apenas para retornar o nome da coluna:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.mes_valor (@mes INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @mes_valor NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @mes_valor = (SELECT case @mes
            WHEN 1 THEN 'jan_valor'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'fev_valor'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'mar_valor'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'abr_valor'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'mai_valor'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'jun_valor'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'jul_valor'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'ago_valor'
            WHEN 9 THEN 'stm_valor'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'out_valor'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'nov_valor'
            WHEN 12 THEN 'dez_valor'
        END)
    RETURN @mes_valor
END
```

Ao efetuar o `SELECT` como demonstrado anteriormente, o `SQL SERVER` interpreta como uma `string`, mantendo a consulta estática, exemplo:

```
VALOR
jan_valor
ago_valor
dez_valor
```

Quando deveria retornar o valor da coluna

```
VALOR
10.3
23.1
55.2
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144285/pivot-sql-colunas-din%C3%A2micas-com-vari%C3%A1vel/144313#144313

Comment: O porém na tua resposta é que o valor é definido anteriormente à consulta, o valor que preciso passar está atrelado ao relacionamento, a coluna `tabela_relacionada.data_emissao`.

Comment: Quando você chama sua FUNCTION dbo.mes_valor (@mes INT) ela só ira retorna isso mesmo, ou seja  WHEN 1 THEN 'jan_valor' , no lugar do seu  'jan_valor' você teria que fazer um select para obter o valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode usar uma `FUNCTION` ou qualquer outro procedimento dentro de um `select` para retorna um nome de coluna da *tabela ou view* que você esta usando, porque o retorno dentro de um `select` nesse caso já é o valor da coluna, ou seja quando você chama sua function ela já retorna o valor para cada linha do `select` como você retorna um nome de coluna teria que executa o select novamente para que o sql saiba que aquele nome retorno seria um nome da coluna da tabela e não seu valor.

Existe 3 formas para você fazer isso.

Primeira;

Altere sua FUNCTION para retorna o valor da coluna e não o nome.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.mes_valor (@mes INT)
RETURNS numeric
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @mes_valor numeric
    SET @mes_valor = (SELECT case @mes
            WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT jan_valor FROM tabela) 
            ..........
        END)
    RETURN @mes_valor
END
```

Segunda;

Faça seu case no próprio select.

```
SELECT
 case 
      WHEN MONTH(tabela_relacionada.data_emissao) = 1 THEN jan_valor 
 ..........
 end as valor 
FROM tabela
```

Terceira;

Essa seria a mais desaconselhável, você teria que armazenar seu select em uma string(varchar) para só depois executa a consulta através do `execute();`

Algo do tipo;

```
declare @query varchar(max);

set @query = "SELECT  [dbo.mes_valor(MONTH(tabela_relacionada.data_emissao))] as valor FROM tabela";

execute(@query);
```

Veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/144285/pivot-sql-colunas-din%C3%A2micas-com-vari%C3%A1vel/144313#144313).